# Jquery CSS duration not working in Safari Ios 9

Tags: ios, css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm changing the CSS animation duration via jquery:

```
 $('img').css({'-webkit-animation-duration':  time+'s' });
```

It's working in Chrome but not in Safari, even if I have the -webkit- prefix.

Here's a Codepen Example:
http://codepen.io/Vin-ni/pen/pjMVrK

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Asses a codepen example. Sorry :)